# Prove that $U$ and $V$ are Isomorphic

Tags: linear-algebra, sequences-and-series, vector-spaces, linear-transformations, computer-science

Let there be $V$ vector space of all Converging sequences with real numbers:

---

$V$ = {($a_1,a_2,a_3,...) \in\ V|$ $\forall i \in \mathbb {N}$: $a_i \in\ \mathbb{R}$ & $\exists$ $lim_{ n\to\infty}a_n$ }

$U$ = {($a_1,a_2,a_3,...) \in\ V|$ $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=0$ },
In other words - $U$ is the subset in $V$ that contains all of real sequences converging to $0$


Prove that $V$ and $U$ are Isomorphic

---

> **MY METHOD**:
>  I tried to come up with this linearic transformation:
> ($a_1,a_2,a_3,...)$ $\rightarrow $ ($a_1 - \lim_{n\to\infty}a_n$
> ,$a_2$ - $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n$,$a_3$ -
> $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n$,...)
>  But this is **NOT** an INJECTIVE linearic
> transformation
>
> ---
>
> **Why?**: 
>  *For Example:* 
>  Lets us take
> two different Converging sequences: $(1,$ $\frac12$, $\frac13$,
> $\frac14$,$...)$ and $(2,$ $\frac32$, $\frac43$, $\frac54$,$...)$ are
> being sent to the same output.

Comment: it looks like $U=V$ in your definition.

Comment: Fixed the problem in $V$

Comment: If you have infinite-dimensional vector spaces $V$, $W$ then finding a non-injective surjection or a non-surjective injection does not imply that the spaces are not isomorphic. Think of the space $V$ of all sequences and the space $W$ of all sequences with first entry equal to zero. Then obviously $W$ is strictly contained in $V$, but still $W$ is isomorphic to $V$. Just map $(a_n)$ to $(b_n)$ with $b_0=0$ and $b_{i+1}=a_i$.

Comment: @Gae.S. SORRY now I see

Comment: You could come up with an isomorphism from $V$ to $\mathbb{R}\oplus U$ using your approach (the leading $\mathbb{R}$ is the limit).  Then, it comes down to showing that $\mathbb{R}\oplus U$ is isomorphic to $U$.  This can be shown since $U$ is infinite dimensional (see @Daniel's comment).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Combining the proposals in the comments with your attempt, we can actually come up with an isomorphism:

For a sequence $(a_n)\in V$ let $\alpha:=\lim_na_n$, and define
$$\varphi((a_1,a_2,\dots)):=(\alpha,\,a_1-\alpha,\,a_2-\alpha,\,\dots)\,.$$
You can easily write up its inverse.

Comment: But if you will take for example: $T$(1, 1/2, 1/3...)$ := $(0, 1, 1/2, 1/3,...) will the '0' have an origin?

Comment: How do you mean 'origin' here? Is $T=\varphi$? Could you find its inverse?

Comment: yes $T$ = $φ $ . and origin means the input ( for example: 1 is the input and 1/2 is the output in this linear transformation )

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. The first coordinate of $\varphi(a)$ is the limit of sequence $a$ and $a$ itself is encoded shifted to the second coordinate (and subtracting the limit).